# Comparing dictionary to itself? python

Tags: python, dictionary

So lets say I have an initial dictionary like this:

```
color = {'blue': 1, 'red': [], 'green':[]}
```

And after my code is run I end up with this:

```
color = {'blue':[] , 'red': [], 'green':1}
```

How do I compare an initial key blue with the final key green to see if the key values are the same? I also want to check if red remains empty.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) beforehand to make a copy of the original dictionary.

```
import copy
color = {'blue': 1, 'red': [], 'green':[]}
original_colors = copy.deepcopy(color)
```

Then afterwards, you can check like this:

```
if original_colors['blue'] == color['green']:
    ...
```